# Opera and Chrome wrong <td> height when having child <img> with height,width set

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table, opera

In the following code example on opera version 53.0.2907.99 and chrome version 67.0.3396.87 on windows 10 enterprise 1803, from some reason the left td gets different height (36px) than the right td (35.6px).
When researching I saw that if we add more td's then exactly those td's which have that img as a child, will have the wrong smaller height (35.6px instead of 36px)

[image]

Here is the a code to reproduce the problem:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
img {
    height: 34px;
    width: 34px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: block;
}
td {
background-color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="background:black;color: white;">
    <table style="background-color: red;width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse">
        <tbody>
            <tr role="row" style="background: yellow">
                <td>a</td>
                <td><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/wAALCABQAFABAREA/8QAHAAAAQUBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAABgADBAUHAgEI/8QANhAAAQMDAgQDBQgBBQAAAAAAAQIDBAAFEQYhEhMxQQdRcRQiYZGhIzJCUmKBscHRM0Ph8PH/2gAIAQEAAD8A3+lTbryGW1OOKCUJGSonAHqaBrn4u6Vtr62RLclOJOCIzfEM+XF0qmX452ok8qzT1p8ypCfpmpDHjXaFbyLVcmk+aeWv+FUQWbxM0pe3ksMXNLD6jhLUpJaJ9Cdj86Ls0qVKgjxC1yzpSAG2XkG4ujLTPU+pHYf4rArhe79qV9S7jcZDyFHdBWQj9kjbFcsWh0pHC2SPgOtW0W1v4AEXYfpqebWVJAUxj0FR39OsuoIUj5d6LtGa4e0nFVb7yt+Vb0Echz7zjA7p/Un+K1q0Xy236GJVsmNSGj1KDuD5EdjVjQxrrVbWkdOuziAuQo8thv8AMs/0Opr5jXMmXy8OS5ry3pDyipa1HJNFUC1H3PsyRiiuDbVAJCW8/tVu3b1p/wBs/KpCbanG6QKYfgNp6jaqm52xp1glKRms7jXSfpDVAftz6mkLVkt591fmD/ntX0jpHUbOprG3Na2VnhWk44kqHUHHf/2sx8d31uyLTFT/AKaAta/LiPT6A1mul4ntVywRsK1yFAQhKUhO2KvIkZKRsBUpaMYA7nFeNJDiSfLamZLQCTneqeRHyDjpist1pC5byFAYVxZFFPgVdJKdS3ODwrXEfZDhJH3Fg7Z8sgqH7CpfjqoxplsytJDxUvhzuOEBP91nOmJioctTiQVelFsi6X/HNakIZSRgJ4gP5qO3qHVDLo5U5l7HVIWk/Siqy6jvUpIEuHxKTvxJO1R7nfdRxyv2aKltIOcrOxHwqgTd9UyllS7k2hX5OYkfSrRuZfYTQelOIkNHdXCQSPlQ5rWSJcePJaIBwcg0Q+AUd8367SEqPJDCULGdioqyDjv0NWnjVZn7nKZkx2ytUVkcYAyeEk/waz/RMLnvvZzgJO/kauHdFLmqlmW7zVujCCpRwj4gVIhaMYj21cZxCHZKlhYkoSEKRgYASB9c9aKtIQ37fzI77pOTkA9qf1DBkTXS37xawR7p6HzoKuGimprTLbSGmXWividI4i4FfmCu4p6JpORClsGG+tplKAlaOYSF46nHmaha+hNIhsBtO5cwflWmeFlsbtbPJS0lC1xULWoDcnO/1NW2tYziFolJH2TiA2tQ7EE4z6gms8sduat9wk/d+1USOGi1llopyUhQ8jXb7jEKI9I5ScNpKsAVW6fnw5ElRMttT595xIIyAfh5VcT5UNmaG2ZLa18PFwE749K8cDSzlTaT6imSy3nKUgUN362tzXIoUUjhc4yVeQo80VGdKHJiweXwcpBP4t8k+nSit9hqSytl5CVtrGFJUMgis71NplqyKamwy6Yyl8LgWrPLJ6Y+HbemYj6Fo+9uK8Te7Y5lsTY5O6VJKh/FV7llsDr4kNobbdHRxlfCfp2qeyi2sYKQ0OHfiUcn1JrtV4gF5LXtbJWo4SArJNOOSG2sgq3q2telYt0itS5peAJyhtK+EKT8ds70YNNNsNJaaQlDaBhKUjAArumpEdqXHcYfQFtOJKVJPcVkd6gydN3j2dZKo6/eYcP4k+R+I6H/AJqT7NCujCea02ojpxIBqA9YojJ2tqXD5tq4f7FSY1nirQMwEM+ZUeLP1qyahx4qCGmkAdThIFd2C0LvN1Ut5OYjRy5+ryT/AN7VpAASkAAADbAr2lSrPfE5hMgWxCThxPNIx1/DQFCvq4CuRJSQRtkVPd1RDxnnAY7Um9UxnUjhdyfhTzd0kTvsmkkJPc0V6Qv6WLU6iPZ7nKSH1JLrDSCnIwCN1A0YWa7x75a2rhFS4lpwqAS6nCgUkpIIye4qfX//2Q=="></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Its a real problem because we have a situation where that missing 0.4px displayed the wrong background color.

NOTE: Does not happen in firefox.
NOTE: Removing height, width from the img tag makes the two tds have the same height.

Edit:
After setting padding: 0 on tds there is still 0.4px difference:

[image]

Edit2:
Applying answer below regarding padding and margin of html, body didnt help:

[image]

Edit3:
[image]

Edit4:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: On which operating system?

Comment: windows 10 enterprise 1803

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem  on windows 10 with chrome `67.0.3396.87` (If I save the given code as is in an `index.html`). Have you tried to start chrome without any extensions enabled. Maybe an extension is messing around.

Comment: Disabled all extensions and even opened the html file in anonymous tab and still 0.4px difference.

Comment: Bug happens also in opera 53.0.2907.99

Comment: Removing height, width from the img tag makes the two tds have the same height

Comment: *"Applying answer below regarding padding and margin of html, body didnt help"* First off that is not `margin:0` and `padding:0` applied to just `html` and `body`, that is applied to **everything**.  A `*` selector means **everything**. You need to read carefully before saying something is "wrong"

Comment: BTW Edit 2 is exactly the same image as the first image posted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsBTc.png . So how can Edit 2 be a screenshot of my Snippet?

Comment: @zer00ne I am sorry but your answer is wrong and the image is a printscreen of your snippet (includes the button of executing the snippet, the images in the post got massed up by stackoverflow editing)

Comment: @GuyL. Take another screenshot of my answer exactly like this: https://ibb.co/e7BeSy , Leave the `computed ` tab open. I'm certain that you have modified the style through the dev tools. You said: *"Its a real problem because we have a situation where that missing 0.4px displayed the wrong background color."*  And the original image you posted: https://ibb.co/j1jF0J  indeed coincides with what you claimed. Your new image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsBTc.png is supposed to be from my answer yet clearly it conflicts with my screenshot: https://ibb.co/e7BeSy .

Comment: @zer00ne see edit3

Comment: @zer00ne I am expecting an apology for your false claims.

Comment: I acknowledge that there is a bug and that you are wasting our time without knowing the solution to it.

Comment: How can it be a bug if no one but you sees it?

Comment: 3 screenshots of my answer, make 3 **exactly** like mine. Then there would be little doubt. Test 1: https://ibb.co/i67hhy , Test 2: https://ibb.co/fc0PvJ , Test 3: https://ibb.co/jGLeUd . I know the solution, you don't understand it apparently. It's very basic and simple, ask *"the people you work with"*,

Comment: @zer00ne See my edit4

Comment: Please explain why there's a browser default property missing 0.4px each? https://ibb.co/fCCCXy

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the Google Chrome user-agent adds a padding, by default, to many elements.

You can override the user-agent rule in this way:

```
td {
  padding: 0;
}
```

To avoid further problems, you can use one of many [CSS reset stylesheets](https://css-tricks.com/reboot-resets-reasoning/).

Comment: (-1) That is wrong. Does not effect the problem stated in any way. Still 0.4 px difference between the two tds. We have this problem on our production website which has all possible reset stylesheets and I just gave a minimal example to remove all the other noise.

Comment: It works for me, Google Chrome 67 and Windows 10 Home

Comment: After setting it, the left td has height of 34.4 and the right one 34.

Answer (score 0):

Reset `margin: 0` and `padding: 0`, and insure `html` and `body` have width and height set explicitly. The img is a block and therefore its height will affect the `<td>` because a `<td>` will want to conform with the height of its content. This is not a problem if img is `inline` since height of `inline` elements do not affect its surroundings as `block` and `inline-block` does.

### Demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0
    }
    
    img {
      height: 34px;
      width: 34px;
      margin-right: 6px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      display: block;
    }
    
    td {
      background-color: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="background:black;color: white;">
  <table style="background-color: red;width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tbody>
      <tr role="row" style="background: yellow">
        <td>a</td>
        <td><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wrong. See my edit2 in the question. Running your code snippet directly in the browsers shows 0.4px height difference.

Comment: Here's screenshots of my answer as rendered in a Snippet: https://ibb.co/e7BeSy
https://ibb.co/mvMPud Nope, I don't see it, explain to me what exactly you do in order to get a result such as that from my answer? I cannot reproduce this problem unless I intentionally add `0.4px margin` to get the result of the first example and I'd have to intentionally add `0.4px padding` to Edit 2.

Comment: If you can't find a solution it doesn't mean that I am trying to intentionally waste my time here.

Comment: I assume you haven't looked at the screenshots that include not only the undeniable fact that there is no 34.4px dimension, but also the fact that it is indeed my answer. Note there is your rude comment and then my rude reply in said images. Retake the screenshot exactly the way I did it. Use the computed tab.

Comment: Here's the original image you posted: https://ibb.co/j1jF0J . It clearly shows that you did have a problem. Compare the present screenshots and that is no longer a problem that you still claim to have. I have no idea why you insist on the contrary when the evidence is at hand.